# Laravel 5.1 : Looking for ajax script to validate form on modal dialog

Tags: php, ajax, validation, modal-dialog, laravel-5.1

I'm newbie in ajax ^^', so I'm looking for an ajax script to validate my form on a modal dialog using laravel 5.1 rules, especially unique rule on create and update.
Please any one would help me :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a good script
https://github.com/JesseLeite/Laravel-Bootstrap-Modal-Form

Thanks JesseLeite :))

Answer (score 0):

You should really google these things before asking on stackoverflow.

Client side validation:
http://www.bootply.com/waK1iLoXCi

Server side validation:

Read this and apply: https://laravel.com/docs/5.1/validation